# Can't reach internet after reboot. But I can ping DNS servers Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: networking, dns, openvpn, 23.10

A fresh install 23.10 with UFW and OpenVPN, all works no problem. Then, after a restart, the network icon comes up with a question mark. And I can't reach the internet. I can ping whatever IP I want, like the Google DNS 8.8.8.8, or something else, just not ping by name, e.g.

```
ping www.google.com
temporary failure in name resolution
```

This has never happened before with my Ubuntu over the last 10 years. But it started like 1 month ago. I gave up after hours of troubleshooting. So, I just reinstalled it, and it worked, and now it stopped again.

So, I have tried:

1. Removing the OpenVPN
2. Deactivating the UFW
3. Setting manual IP and DNS

Nothing works, and it's starting to annoy me as it should just work. So, there is something blocking, but what? Been using hours on trying to figure out a solution to this. So, need some help here.